# Link a new page on exsting page with the new page having a transperent background

Tags: css, html

I am trying to add a new page by providing the link on the existing page. 
For example, In the attached image AMT_Sample.png you can see two pages existing page and new page. The New page here loads from the links provided in the existing Page. Now I want to make the New page background transparent so that the it doesn't look like a different page. I cant add Existing Page background to New page because there a some padding in the new page i.e. new page starts after some padding in the existing page. I want to get the page as AMT_Sample2.png. How can i make this by changing the CSS

**AMT_Sample.png**

[image]

**AMT_Sample2.png**

[image]

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming the "new page" isn't actually a new page but rather an element e.g. a <section> that gets shown? Can you show some code?

Comment: I am so confused after reading your question. Please be clear and add the relevant code.

Comment: The existing page is a already existing application and new page is a new Application I made, i want to integrate this new page(new website) in the existing one. The existing one is built in struts and the Application i built is in Bootstrap and AngularJS and  I want to integrate it to the existing one. I have just created a tab in existing application and provided a link to my new application. Now when I click on the tab it redirects to my application. and the UI is completely different. I want to match the UI using Bootstrap framework.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with transparent layers. sounds to me like you need to adjust all your styles to change the look of your bootstrap application so it looks like the old one. that's not something anyone here can provide a single answer to.